# How do I include a build flag to docker when executed from GitLab runner locally?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm debugging a docker build of an image locally hoping get a better idea why the build fails. I'm running GitLab CI runner locally:

```
gitlab-runner exec docker build https://gitlab.com/happy_hedgehog/another_tdd.git#production:services/client test-driven-client:09d8s4324kk -f Dockerfile-prod --build-arg REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=""
```

the runner throws `FATAL: flag provided but not defined: -f` meaning it doesn't understand the flag. It's the docker flag that specifies which file to start building from. How can I work around this ?

I checked the `gitlab-runner help` section but couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that in GitLab today.  There is an open issue (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22801) to allow the specification of an alternate Dockerfile.

Comment: Yeah the issue hasn't been closed as solved or fixed. Looks like GitLab CI doesn't support that such thing locally atm. Gotta find another way of debugging the build.

Comment: That's right.  I've got a debugging tip in my CI/CD tutorial at
https://gitpitch.com/atsaloli/cicd/master?grs=gitlab#/138  (it takes a few seconds to come up).   I'll excerpt it here:  "Pro tip: to keep a container running so you can login and poke around, add a sleep loop command to your script ... Now you can run `docker ps` to get the container id, and start an interactive session with `docker exec -it /bin/bash`  (See the link for properly formatted example.)